# jQuery datepicker() - defaulting to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I select a date on the datepicker, I need it
to default to yyyy/mm/dd

When I do the following:

```
     $(id).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

and select a field, the datepicker does not even come up.

Is there anything wrong with what I have above?

obviously

```
     $(id).datepicker();
```

work but it does not form that date the way I like it " yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: You need to "attach" a jQuery UI component *before* trying to invoke methods (or set options) that it provides against an element. With the latest jQuery UI versions, that may have thrown an Exception (see the error console). While the posted answers show a better way to do it,  `$(id).datepicker(); $(id).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'yyyy/mm/dd');` is also valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formatting use:

```
$("#your_ID").datepicker({dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd"});
```

For getting value of date use this:

```
var date = $("#your_ID").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd' }).val();
```

Comment: The current dateFormat uses yy to signify a 4 digit year.  Not yyyy.

Answer (score 2):

When you init it, you pass an option object :

```
$(id).datepicker({dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd"});
```

Comment: The current dateFormat uses yy to signify a 4 digit year.  Not yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(id).datepicker({dateFormat: **value**});
```

Fill **value** with one of this :

- **Default**, shows mm/dd/yy
- **ISO 8601**, shows yy-mm-dd
- **Short**, shows d M, y
- **Medium**, shows d MM, y
- **Full**, shows DD, d MM, yy