# Format datepicker date to YYYYMMDD

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm getting the data from the jquery datepicker plugin. This is the exact date that I'm getting: Thu Apr 02 2015.
How do I format it into this: 20150402 ??

I've tried some things but nothing is working so far. This is my code so far:

```
$("#button").click(function(){

                var datum = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
                console.log(datum);



            });
```

Comment: `var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyymmdd' }).val();`

Comment: are you using php at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker - Change Date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449803/jquery-datepicker-defaulting-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

`getDate` returns a date object, so you can just extract from that

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var datum     = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
    var formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', datum);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p2hc170h/2/)

Changing the date format in the datepicker settings would change the format of the value passed, but not the format of the date object retrieved with `getDate`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can check the follows:

```
var datum = $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyymmdd' }).val();
console.log(datum);
```